Application degrades when new revision is updated because of "volume is already used by pod(s)"
When using a deployment that has a PVC attached (using AWS EBS CSI Driver), everytime a new revision is rolled out, the application goes into degraded state.
Looking at it, I can see that there are 2 revisions of the replicaSet:

revision 1 (old one): that is still running
revision 2 (new one): stuck in init phase.

Problem is that Kubernetes waits until new revision is healthy before killing the old one, but the new one can be started because the volume is attached to the old pod.
Solution would be to manually kill the old revision pod. an then new one will start successfully.
Any other solution that does not need  manual intervention?
PS: revision 1 and revision 2 are in different nodes.
PVC is in mode ReadWriteOnce, and I would prefer to keep it that way.

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

"PVC is in mode ReadWriteOnce, and I would prefer to keep it that way." - You need a ReadWriteMany PVC if both deployments (old and new) need to access it at the same time (which they shortly need for a zero downtime deployment). If this it not an option, you may want to use a StatefulSet instead of a Deployment.

Alternatively, you can set the the strategy type of the deployment set to Recreate instead of RollingUpdate

Thanks, Recreate should fix my current issue.
